# Bring a window to front in applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

This is probably a total newbie question but here it is. I am making a pure applescript application. It activates another app and then types. The problem is that when it activates the app, it doesn't bring the apps window to the front. I tried telling the app to activate:

```
tell application "app_name.app"
activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "test"
end tell
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Which application are you targeting?

Comment: Terminal for the moment. I might need to access other apps too. Is there a universal command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the target application has no open windows, you have to reopen a default window:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 4):

To open the Terminal in foreground you need to run:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "echo hi"
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way of executing commands in Terminal is:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "echo hi"
end tell
```

Comment: And how do you then make the terminal window foremost?

Comment: @marcelnijman: `set frontmost to true`

Answer (score 0):

If the application is already open and you just want to bring it to the front, try:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Your_Application_Name"
    set frontmost to true
end tell
```